# my export in yii2 using kartik-v/yii2-export not working

Tags: yii2, export-to-excel, kartik-v

i am trying to use kartik export and its not working for me. In config file I have added following code:

```
'modules' => [
    'gridview' => [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
        ],
     ],
```

In Composer i have added folowing code

```
"kartik-v/yii2-export": "@dev",
"kartik-v/yii2-mpdf":"@dev",
"kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev"
```

My view code is like this:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use yii\bootstrap\Tabs;
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="general-info-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php 
    <p>
     <?= Html::a('create', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php 
    $gridColumns = [
     'sfcl_name',
     [
        'attribute'=> 'org_type',
        'value' => 'orgType.cv_lbl'
     ],
  ];

  echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns
  ]);
?>
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'pjax'=>true,   
        'columns' => [
            'sfcl_name',
            'phone',
            [
             'attribute'=>'regd_dt_ad', 
             'format'=>['date', 'php:Y-M-d'], 
             'xlFormat'=>'mmm\-dd\, yyyy',  // different date format
             'width'=>'100px'
             ],
             [
             'attribute'=> 'org_type',
             'value' => 'orgType.cv_lbl'
             ],
           ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

My controller code is:

```
My controller code to call this view : public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new SfclGeneralSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

On click of export menu nothing is happening.In tutorial i saw there were options for exporting to pdf ,html,csv,json,text.such options doesnot appers in my case.Is the css not working or what?

Comment: You have error ?   .. show your related  controller/action

Comment: there are no errors.excel View drop down button doesn't works.I have added my controller code.

Answer (score 0):

you run "composer update" command?.

also in your web.php

```
'modules' => [
'gridview' => [
    'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
    ],
 ],
```

add the property downloadAction, like this:

```
'modules' => [
               'gridview' =>  [
                    'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
                    'downloadAction' => 'gridview/export/download',
                ]
            ],
```